# "hot for what you got"

Tags: phrases, expressions

The dialogue in an American TV show goes like this

> It's just that he walked you to the door, and where I come from, that means he's hot for what you got.

How can we rephrase "hot for what you got"? I'm trying to keep the meaning as close as possible in the translated version.

Comment: If you're translating it, why do you need it rephrased in English?

Comment: To put it indirectly, he walked you to the door, and would very much like an invitation to enter your home, in order to get to know you better. OTOH if he wasn't so keen, he would have let you walk to your door alone. See [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hot) meaning **3**.

Comment: Welcome! Take a moment to read over [the topics that are covered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for writing advice. But if you're having trouble understanding the phrase, please edit to indicate that. (But the answer is, it means "he is attracted to you," with a rhyme for humorous effect.)

Comment: *Hot for* strongly suggests erotic interest. He was excited to get in ... past your front door and inside.